# Why My Checkboxes Doesn't Check Back After Uncheck in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, formik

I have checkboxes that you can click as many as you want.
My problem is that it doesn't put a check after I uncheck. Also the values when I submit is not appearing in console.log

Pls check my codesandbox here
[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-styled-components-beqzn?file=/src/Form.js)

```
  <Label htmlFor={id}>
      <Input
        type="checkbox"
        id={name}
        name={name}
        value={value}
        checked={checked}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <Indicator />
    </Label>


  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {products.map((product) => (
        <div key={product}>
          <Input
            name={values.products}
            value={values.products}
            checked={values.products}
            onChange={({ target }) => setFieldValue("products", target.value)}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Hi Joseph, it is likely you were downvoted because you have not supplied enough context in your question and your codesandbox link is 404ing. I would recommend posting the entire component as well as an example of any objects you are using (i.e. products) as well as any console errors.

Comment: I'm not the downvote but would guess that it's because your explanation of the issue is _really_ confusing, and the `<label>` code in the question conflicts with that in the `form` so it's not clear which code you're having trouble with.

Comment: Looking at the codepen, the problem is caused by the fact that in your onChange handler you're trying to read the checkbox value from the DOM instead of from state, so it's always empty.

Comment: @StiyAle. I think my codesandbox link is accessible.

Comment: @DanielBeck. my checkboxes just doesn't work.

Comment: @Joseph why are you passing what appears to be a list of products to the `name`, `values` and `checked` props? I would expect that to be something specific to the product the person is selecting. The checked prop controls if a value is checked or not and is expecting a boolean or undefined

Comment: @StiyAle. yeah I'm confused right now how to fix this. maybe u can help me check the `formik` docs cause I'm using that for the form.

Comment: how your output should look when you click on submit ? what is the expected structure ?

Comment: @Shyam.  like this `["Macbook"]`. whatever has a check on it

Comment: @Joseph have added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are checking a checkbox your will get the value and check whether if the value is present already in the products list if it is not present then you should add the value ( this will be your check part ) else you can filter the value from the products ( this will be your uncheck ) .

```
 <Checkbox
            name="products"
            value={product}
            checked={values.products.includes(product)}
            onChange={({ target }) => {
              let updatedProducts;
              if (values.products.includes(product)) {
                updatedProducts = values.products.filter(
                  (product) => product !== target.value
                );
              } else {
                updatedProducts = [...values.products, target.value];
              }
              setFieldValue("products", updatedProducts);
            }}
          />
```

**Working Sandbox**

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-styled-components-forked-c16gc?file=/src/Form.js)

Answer (score 0):

values.products is an array of your values, so it doesn't make sense to have this for your name or value. Instead, you need to pick out the specific value from the array that is relevant to your specific checkbox.

```
      {products.map((product, index) => (
         <div key={product}>
           <p>{product}</p>
           <Input
             name={product}
             value={values.products[index]}
             checked={values.products[index]}
             onChange={({ target }) => setFieldValue(`products.${index}`,!values.products[index])
        }
      />
          </div>
     ))}
```

[Working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-styled-components-forked-z2gsw?file=/src/Form.js)

Comment: Could you fork my codesandbox? Maybe its better doing the `formik` way

Comment: Sure. Here is the forked version - https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-styled-components-forked-z2gsw?file=/src/Form.js

Comment: One other thing you have to do is initialize initial checkbox values to false - lines 10 and 11 in my fork...

Comment: Thank you. Please make the console.log values something like this `["Macbook"]`

Comment: if that's what you want, it makes more sense to store the values as an Object instead of an Array - so, something like {Macbook: false, XP: true... and so on